# ¿Como eliminar el cache del navegador desde mi servidor?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, web

Cuando hago cambios no se ven reflejados en el navegador, sin embargo, cuando se borra el cache del navegador se reflejan los cambios, existe una manera para que se haga de manera automática. utilizo laravel y vue...

Comment: ¿Conocés el concepto de _asset versioning_?

Comment: Cache bursting, añade un `?v=2` al final de tu ruta por ejemplo, no sirve de nada pero hará que el navegador lo vea diferente a la versión cacheada. Todo depende de qué es lo que te está dando problemas y qué tan frecuentemente necesitas cambiarlo. A unas malas puedes incluso hacer que cada archivo se sirva con un timestamp al final, lo que hará que siempre se ignore la caché... Pero no es recomendable, al final la caché está para ahorrar tiempos de carga y hacer las cosas más fluidas, ignorarla siempre no es buena práctica. Como digo, depende mucho de qué necesites, no das mucha información!

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: hay muchas formas pero aquí hay una https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27503888/laravel-sending-no-cache-header, https://luisdalmolin.dev/blog/invalidate-http-cache-with-laravel/